# Abelian sub-W*-algebras

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, fa.functional-analysis

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra which acts faithfully on a Hilbert space of density character $\kappa$ but does not on a Hilbert space of density character $\lambda<\kappa$ (that is, the density character of the predual $M_0$ is $\kappa$. Does $M$ contain a subalgebra *-isomorphic to $\ell^\infty(\kappa)$? Does $M_0$ contain a complemented subspace isomorphic as a Banach space to $\ell_1(\kappa)$?

---

A density character is the minimal cardinality of a dense set.

Comment: What is the density character of a Hilbert space?

Comment: The smallest cardinality that a dense set can have, which for an infinite dimensional Hilbert space  is the same as its orthonormal dimension. 

Answer (score 10):

This is not true.  Popa showed in "[Orthogonal pairs of ∗-subalgebras in finite von Neumann algebras](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=703810)" (1983), that if $F$ is a free group with arbitrary cardinality than any abelian von Neumann subalgebra of the group von Neumann algebra $LF$ must have separable predual.

Edit:  This doesn't even hold when $M$ is abelian since $\ell^\infty(\mathbb R)$ has no faithful state and hence does not embed into any $\sigma$-finite von Neumann algebra.

Comment: This brings to my mind the following question: Is always the cardinality of pure states on a given von Neumann algebra greater than the cardinality of the algebra itself?